# Create trigger that gives warning/error

Tags: mysql, triggers

Need help for creating trigger using phpmyadmin that will give warning before inserting data. The situation is much like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER secure_item
   BEFORE INSERT
   ON item
BEGIN
   IF (TRIM(TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'DAY')) IN ('SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY'))
      OR (     TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24')) NOT BETWEEN 8 AND 15 )
   THEN
      raise_application_error (-20500,

                               'You may insert into test table only during business hours.'
      );
   END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: i used this previously in oracle and it worked, but not in mysqli/mysql . Any suggestion?

Comment: Check the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace sysdate with

```
NOT hour(now()) between 8 and 15 OR weekday(now()) > 4
```